# Jupyter notebook not directing to browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have install jupyter notebook with command line by using "pip" in mine window 10.Its successfully installed.
But when i tried to run notebook by typing "jupyter notebook" in command line,it's isn't worked .
[when press enter its stick on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CapY.jpg)

Comment: Can you open another terminal and check if this process is running or is it just not recognising the command ? what if you type `jupyter notebook --version`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.